# Any way to apply sort of a JPA AttributeConverter over an Embeddable class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I'd like to post-process my embeddable class to convert it to another type

```
@Embeddable
public class Identity { 
  private Long id;
  private String alias;
}


@Embeddable
public class virtualIdentities { 
  private Long id;
  private List<String> aliases; //AttributeConverter applied from a ","-joined string
}


@Entity
public class Parent {

  private Identity identity; //Works flawlessly
  private VirtualIdentities vIdentities; //Works flawlessly but...
  private List<Identity> vIdentities; //<- That is what I'd like to achieve!!
}
```

So I am looking for a mechanism (standard JPA preferrably) that allows me to map someway a `VirtualIdentities` embeddable instance as a `List<Identity>`

If only I could do `AttributeConverter<List<Identity>,VirtualIdentities>` ...